# How do I make the number to perfectly center to the circle in Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I am using Google Slides to create some prototype designs.

If the circle is a bit small, the number would not be fit to the center.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **`"Align" --> "center"`** option from the menu.

[image]

Comment: Weird, I tried but it's not working. Do you mind publishing your slide? Thanks very much.

Comment: How did you create your circle and text? It should be by creating the circle using `shape` from the menu.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 4):

Align center alone does not work.

In the “Formatting options” panel change the left and right padding values to zero and then the “align center” will center the number.

if you are having vertical centering issues do the same for top and bottom padding and align top and bottom. [image]

Here is the slide deck demonstrating this phenomenon

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-NN-c1spYshDfEZRyMNlepjwvjgc5c_MF6qohfveCns/edit

Comment: Please be more specific regarding the cases where align center alones doesn't work.

Comment: The reply by the originating poster is the case where it doesn’t work.

Comment: The OP accepted the previous answer so it looks that OP someway finally make it work.

Comment: This is how I made it work. Do you disagree with my solution? @AGamePlayer how did you resolve?

Comment: This answer worked for me, directly in google draw. Noting I could not make this work using the embedded google draw inside of google docs (haven't tried google slides) ref: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202418474?hl=en&msgid=202828482